# how to write XML schema for iptables packet filter to validate IP packets?

Tags: android, xsd, firewall

How can I implement an IP tables packet filter using an XML schema to validate IP packets and to generate firewall rule-sets that will be saved in separate xml file? Later this rule-sets will be used to compare incoming packets.

I want to use this functionality for a open source firewall application which I want to design for Android phone.

Comment: have you an exemple of xml file ip packets like you want ?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to achieve exactly. Are the XML schemas the rueles? Can you expand the question - maybe with an example?